# How to solve 'Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')' after already preprocessing using Pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, pipeline, missing-data

There are many posts containing this error, but I couldn't find the solution for this problem. I'm using this [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/camnugent/california-housing-prices). This is what I've done, a preprocessing, with SimpleImputer for categorical and numerical features:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

%load_ext nb_black

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from category_encoders import CatBoostEncoder

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

housing = pd.read_csv("housing.csv")
housing.head()

X = housing.drop(["longitude", "latitude", "median_house_value"], axis=1)
y = housing["median_house_value"]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42
)

numeric_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="median")), ("scaler", StandardScaler())]
)

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="constant")),
        ("encoder", CatBoostEncoder()),
    ]
)


numeric_features = [
    "housing_median_age",
    "total_rooms",
    "total_bedrooms",
    "population",
    "households",
    "median_income",
]

categorical_features = ["ocean_proximity"]

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("numeric", numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
        ("categorical", categorical_transformer, categorical_features),
    ]
)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[("preprocessor", preprocessor), ("regressor", LinearRegression())]
)

lr_model = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

But I got this error:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Any idea of what's happening in here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `CatBoostEncoder` is returning several `nan` values when fitted to the training set, which is why the `LinearRegression` throws an error.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from category_encoders import CatBoostEncoder

housing = pd.read_csv("housing.csv")

X = housing.drop(["longitude", "latitude", "median_house_value"], axis=1)
y = housing["median_house_value"]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="median")),
    ("scaler", StandardScaler())
])

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="constant")),
    ("encoder", CatBoostEncoder())
])

numeric_features = ["housing_median_age", "total_rooms", "total_bedrooms", "population", "households", "median_income"]
categorical_features = ["ocean_proximity"]

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ("numeric", numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
    ("categorical", categorical_transformer, categorical_features),
])

X_new = preprocessor.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)

print(np.isnan(X_new).sum(axis=0))
# array([   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0, 4315])
```

Comment: Did you test the `CatBoostEncoder` on its own, and not in a pipeline together with `SimpleImputer`? Because it seems that it is working fine on its own when applied to the "ocean_proximity" column, which is a little strange ...

Comment: Indeed, the `CatBoostEncoder` works fine by itself. It also works fine in the pipeline if you fit it to the full dataset, for some reason it breaks when you fit the pipeline to the training set only.

Comment: I saw the same. Actually, if you apply `SimpleImputer` and then `CatBoostEncoder` in a sequence, it all seems fine, even for the training data. It is only the pipeline (or more specifically `categorical_transformer`) that introduces `NaN` values.